# Can I use two 'JOIN's in a single call?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to call from 3 different tables all at once.

Table `a` has general data.

Table `td` & `dmd` have specific data to their data points.

My call (simplified) looks like this.

```
SELECT a.*, td.*, dmd.* 
FROM activities as a, tweet_activity_data AS td, direct_message_activity_data AS dmd 
WHERE a.activity_id IN (1,2,3,4,5) 
AND a.activity_id = dmd.id 
AND a.activity_id = td.tweet_id
```

Those last two lines are where I'm having the trouble I think.

I need to get things to line up properly in my response and this just produces no results.

Am I 'allowed' to use two joins like that in a SQL call?

Comment: You can make any number of joins, I am sure you tried running it ?

Comment: You can add as many as necessary. There's no inherent limit.

Comment: Make sure that you have data in the joined table that matches your query.

Comment: From a readability angle, you might want to look at using explicit joins as opposed to implicit (i.e. inner join in this case instead of joining in your `where` condition)

Comment: Emmad, I think you had it right. One table is empty at the moment and as soon as I added some fake data in there the call started working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but to join tables use the JOIN and ON keyword.  Specifically, the stuff currently in your WHERE clause would end up as the ON clauses, telling the query how to join the tables.  So your query would look like

```
SELECT a.*, td.*, dmd.*
FROM activities as a
JOIN tweet_activity_data AS td
  ON a.activity_id = td.tweet_id
JOIN direct_message_activity_data AS dmd
  ON AND a.activity_id = dmd.id
WHERE a.activity_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```